# Combination of set of $x$ objects with another set $y$ objects.

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

Just a question for fun.

How many combinations can be made by combing an element of set of $x$ objects with an element of a set of $y$ objects where here one set is a subset of another. Of course order does not matter $(x_1,y_1)=(y_1,x_1)$.

My approach was to draw a chart $(x_1,x_2,x_3..x_x)$ on one side and $(y_1=x_1,y_2=x_2,..y_x=x_x,..y_y)$ on another, and circle what I found to not be counted twice. This happened to be on the diagonal and places where both elements were not shared by both sets. so through by observations I believe the amount that would not be counted twice is:

$$\min(x,y)+|x-y|\min(x,y)$$

Because there are only $xy$ total pairs (where order does matter), that leaves:

$$xy-\min(x,y)-|x-y|\min(x,y)$$

To be counted twice.

So I believe the answer would be:

$$\min(x,y)+|x-y|\min(x,y)+\frac{xy-\min(x,y)-|x-y|\min(x,y)}{2}=\frac{xy+\min(x,y)+|x-y|\min(x,y)}{2}$$

Is this correct?

Comment: This seems slightly confused. Intuitively the answer should be just $xy$. Is there an issue where objects can be on both sets or something?

Comment: Yes if didn't realize what I was doing. I had one to be ${A,B,C,D}$ and another to be ${A,B,C}$. I have edited my question so that one set is a subset of another . @Stella Biderman please check it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $x=min(x,y)$, so $x$ elements are common in both the sets. First we make a pair out of these $x$ elements. Two choices are there:

a) Elements in pair are different; such pairs will be $x \choose 2$.

b) Elements in pair are identical; such pairs will be $x$.

Second, we make a pair using remaining $y-x$ elements of the bigger set; such pairs will be $x(y-x)$.

Hence, answer is: $x(y-x)+x+ {x \choose 2}$.

Comment: The 'answer' by your approach is also correct as it is exactly the same what I have written :)